# rails simple form for validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I have a `simple_form_for` in Rails. A couple of the fields have validation in the model. I would like this to prevent the form from being submitted if validation fails. That is not happening as I have it coded right now.

Thing Model:

```
validates :name, presence: true
```

form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @thing, html: {class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>
...
<%= f.input :name, label: "Name"%>
....
<div class="modal-footer">
  <%= link_to 'Cancel', [@thing], class: 'btn' %>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" data-disable-with="Saving...">Save</button>
</div>
```

I have tried changing the button to `f.submit` but it seemed to have no change on the functionality. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is my controller create method:

```
  def create
    @thing = Api::Thing.new(params[:api_thing])
    if @thing.valid?
      @thing.active = @thing.active == 'true'

      if @thing.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Thing was successfully created.'
        respond_with @thing
      else 
        flash[:error] = @thing.message
        render 'new'
      end
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you post your controller create method?

Comment: I have added the create method.

Comment: @thing.errors in the create method has the correct values. Is it my final `render 'new'` that is causing trouble?

Comment: I have fixed the main issue by changing my final `render 'new'` to `flash[:error] = @thing.errors.to_a`
`redirect_to :back`, but as it redirects back, it doesn't persist any of the entered data, which would be more desirable. Is there a different command I should use instead?

Comment: It's not clear from your post whether you are trying to validate the model server side or the form input client side. You cannot prevent a form from submitting if validation of the model fails :) Which of the two are your trying to achieve?

Comment: My goal is to stop the form from submitting if the input is not valid. Whatever works best to accomplish that goal is fine with me.